# Plotting two data series in overlapping barplot (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I would like to plot two data series (same type and number of measures, but measured at two timepoints) in the same barplot. Preferably the first series is plotted in grey, with the second series plotted in colours with transparency such that the series 1 data is still visible.
The data I have is of the following format:

```
MyData = data.frame(
  method=rep(c("A","B","C","D","E"),times=3),
  time1=rnorm(30,10,3),
  time2=rnorm(30,8,2),
  lab=rep(rep(c(1,2,3),each=5),times=2),
  cat=rep(c(1,2),each=15)
  )
```

To show the type of plot I'm looking for I have added the code for plotting data series 1 below:

```
p <- ggplot(data = MyData,
            aes(x=lab,
                y=time1,
                fill=method))
p + geom_bar(stat="identity",
             position="dodge",
             alpha=.3) +
  facet_grid(. ~ cat)
```

In the end it doesn't really matter which one of the data series is in grey and which is in colour, as long as they are plotted on top of each other, and both are visible.

All suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

There can only be one active `fill_scale`, so we need to map the variable method to something else, either `group` or `color`.

```
library(ggplot2)

MyData = data.frame(
  method=rep(c("A","B","C","D","E"),times=3),
  time1=rnorm(30,10,3),
  time2=rnorm(30,8,2),
  lab=rep(rep(c(1,2,3),each=5),times=2),
  cat=rep(c(1,2),each=15)
)

p <- ggplot(data = MyData,
            aes(x=lab)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=time2,fill=method),
           stat="identity",
           position="dodge",
           alpha=.3
           ) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=time1,group=method),
           stat="identity",
           position="dodge",
           alpha=.3) +
  scale_fill_discrete() +
  facet_grid(. ~ cat)
p
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. However, as you can see in the plot this is not what I'm looking for, as there are only three grey bars in each plot, and 15 coloured ones.

Comment: I ran into the same issue myself. When `fill` is set to "grey" instead of "method" (in my example), ggplot does not do correct grouping, and plots only one (grey) bar per x-axis value.

Comment: Just use `group` instead of `fill`: `geom_bar(aes(x=lab, y=time1, group=method),  ...)`

Comment: It will be a little bit more readable if you use `colour==method` as well. Still I think it is rather misleading plot in my opinion.

Comment: @zero323 That's actually what I started with. I know realize I do not need the group statement then

Comment: It will need some refinement to make it a well interpretable plot.

Answer (score 2):

I have been thinking about a different way to add the second data series. I can add the second series using `geom_point` instead of `geom_bar`, as this gives less clutter. However, how do I position the points on the corresponding bar? (i.e. right now the points are all on the same x-axis position).

```
library(ggplot2)

MyData = data.frame(
  method=rep(c("A","B","C","D","E"),times=3),
  time1=rnorm(30,10,3),
  time2=rnorm(30,8,2),
  lab=rep(rep(c(1,2,3),each=5),times=2),
  cat=rep(c(1,2),each=15)
)

p <- ggplot(data = MyData,
            aes(x=lab)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=time1,fill=method),
           stat="identity",
           position="dodge",
           alpha=.7
  ) +
  geom_point(aes(y=time2,group=method),
           stat="identity",
           position="dodge",
           alpha=.8,
           size=3) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette=3) +
  facet_grid(. ~ cat)
p
```